# How to rescue a Kubernetes cluster when multiple pods enter "unknown" status

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I am trying to understand the lessons from a failed K8s cluster. I am running Microk8s 1.22.5. I had 3 rock solid (physical) nodes. I tried to add a fourth node (KVM guest) to satisfy the requirements of Minio. Within 24h, the KVM host had entered "unknown" status together with its pods. Within 48h, multiple pods on all of the nodes had "unknown" status. Most of the deployments and statefulsets are down, including multiple DBs (postgres, Elastic) so it's really painful (extra tips on how to save these are welcome). According to the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/):

> A Pod is not deleted automatically when a node is unreachable. The Pods running on an unreachable Node enter the 'Terminating' or
> 'Unknown' state after a timeout. Pods may also enter these states when
> the user attempts graceful deletion of a Pod on an unreachable Node.
> The only ways in which a Pod in such a state can be removed from the
> apiserver are as follows:
>
> 1. The Node object is deleted (either by you, or by the Node Controller).
> 2. The kubelet on the unresponsive Node starts responding, kills the Pod
>    and removes the entry from the apiserver.
> 3. Force deletion of the Pod by
>    the user. The recommended best practice is to use the first or second
>    approach. If a Node is confirmed to be dead (e.g. permanently
>    disconnected from the network, powered down, etc), then delete the
>    Node object. If the Node is suffering from a network partition, then
>    try to resolve this or wait for it to resolve. When the partition
>    heals, the kubelet will complete the deletion of the Pod and free up
>    its name in the apiserver.
>
> Normally, the system completes the deletion once the Pod is no longer
> running on a Node, or the Node is deleted by an administrator. You may override this by force deleting the Pod.

So I tried draining the node (option 1), but no dice. I get some error about not being able to violate a disruption budget. Option 2 is not happening and option 3 has no effect. It looks like the failing node poisoned the whole cluster. Any advice on how to avoid this in the future? Many thanks

Comment: Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Could you also attach what errors did you get? I would be very helpful if you [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by adding [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had to delete the cluster and start from scratch. No data was lost thanks to having used `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain` in my PVs. The system is bare metal.

Comment: Could you show the input of `kubectl describe node`?